# Access nested-stack resources with cdk synth

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to run Synth tests.
I'm doing this by running: app_synth: `CloudAssembly = app.synth()`
And verifying the resources are as expected..

Problem is, I have a nested stack, which I see within my root stack synth output, but I couldn't figure out how to access resources within the nested stack.

Using CDK version 2.128.0.
Python 3.8.15

Comment: FYI: The CDK's [aws-cdk-lib.assertions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html) testing module has native support for asserting against synthed template resources.

Comment: Also merit here is debatable, but I personally will attach nested stacks to the parent stacks and during testing access them through properties